# vs2008 resource editor changes rc file language

Tags: c++, mfc

I am doing some improvements to an application in vs2008 in c++.

When i try to edit resources (for example add an entry in the string table), the vs2008 editor changes the rc file language from `LANG_ENGLISH` to `LANG_NEUTRAL` and a non english text is replaced with question marks.

If i edit the rc file externally (in notepad), and then load it to the vs2008 it works fine.

can anybody help me solve this?
thanks

Shimon

Answer (score 1):

When you expand the String Table node in the Resource View window, you should see the string tables for each individual language.  You add a string to each table by double-clicking them in turn.  The language is automatically set from the string table language.

If you don't see this then the .rc wasn't created properly originally.  Which is common when somebody starts editing it with a text editor.   The resource editor has trouble with .rc files that were created by hand.  You're kinda doomed to keep maintaining it with a text editor.  Which isn't particularly a real problem, the editor isn't exactly user-friendly when adding resource strings in several languages.  Any localization expert I've ever seen doesn't bother with the resource editor.

Comment: I have only one string table node. The string table contains strings in 2 languages - english and hebrew.
Originally adding an entry to the string table didnt cause a problem - i have added an entry myself before, but after a while when i tried to add another entry it causes the problem - in more than one computer.

Comment: Well, yes, that's the source of the problem.